# Talend-Unable to use Context variable in oracle query

Tags: oracle, talend, talend-mdm

I am facing challenge in calling a context variable in my oracle source query

select branch_code from sttms_branch where 
country_code='"+context.con_contry_cd+"'

No rows are fetching.But if we hardcode instead of context.con_contry_cd,then it is working fine
I tried the double quotes at start of select and all possible permuation combinations but nothing is working out.But the context variables are working fine in tmap stage.I am totally stuck up with this issue.Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exact code must be `"select branch_code from sttms_branch where country_code='"+context.con_contry_cd+"'"` or you will get a compilation error.
Also verify the exact value of the context variable (be carefull at white spaces which can be a possible cause of the problem).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes TRF,The issue was with the quotes now it got fixed thanks a lot

Comment: Don't hesitate to mark the question as solved ;) you may also give 1 point ;))